# Fedora 23 lost WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, pci

I upgraded from Fedora 22 (kernel 4.0) to Fedora 23 (kernel 4.2) and now my rtl8192ce WiFi PCI card is not working.

- `lspc` does show the card, but `ifconfig` only shows the devices: `enp2s0`, `lo` and `virbr0`.
- `kinfocenter` shows devices class: 0x00 devices subclass: 0x0D unknown unclassified devices for my PCI WiFi card.
- Even more weird is that tethering from my Android phone also stopped working with the upgrade.

Anyone for a clue what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was some kind of conflict between my nVidia graphics driver/kernel and network. I got network by booting with a kernel where the nVidia graphics driver were not working.

But in the end, I just ended up doing a re-install, and anything is working now :)